# Android GUI : trying to draw on a canvas

Tags: android, view

```
public class Player extends ViewGroup {
    private RectF rect = new RectF();
    private Paint paint;

    public Player(Context context,String pname) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));


    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10, 10, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY(), 10, paint);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int wspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for(int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++){
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.measure(wspec, hspec);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        rect.set(l, t,r, b);
    }
}
```

the third command does draw a red rectangle which bounds are the rect (l,t,r,b) = (412,415,735,754) which is given by the param rect, and for some reason, the two first commands do not do any effect on the canvas!

I have made sure the rect is an actual rectangle, as i mentioned its values were (412,415,735,754) which does make a valid rectangle, and you see how i defined the paint so why the hell wouldnt it draw?

been spending 2 hours trying to figure it out, seriously...

thanks!

BTW, the class extends ViewGroup cause it eventually meant to implement a view container..

Comment: This may be a wild leap, but why are you trying to draw on the canvas of a "ViewGroup" instead of a simple View?

Comment: i am intending it to be a layout manager, and all its children views will be placed on the rounded rectangle that im trying to draw in line 1 of ondraw()

Comment: I have a feeling that you are drawing off screen (or at least out of bounds of you bounding rectangle). The canvas that will be returned to you will be internally defined with top left at 0, 0. Your internal rect should thus have top and left defined as 0, 0, with a width of r - l, and a height of b - t.  While your ViewGroup may or may not be at 0, 0 location, the internal canvas will always draw as if the top left location of the ViewGroup IS 0, 0.

Comment: @trumpetlicks you are right, do you have some tutorial or a further explantion of how the canvas gets changed on the drawing mechanism? cause im struggling here wasting time on stuff that only whoever wrote this system knows... perhaps you should write an answer too so i accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for your onLayout routine:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    rect.set(0, 0, r-l, b-t);
}
```

This way you will create a rect with the width and height of the full layout, but whose top left point (relative to the canvas) is 0, 0.

Comment: that worked, they should have document that the canvas are relative to views bounds, thanks alot! tho i think it is better to get a new rect at the beginning and just call set(l,t,r,b) at the layout, Android discourages allocations on onLayout()

Comment: I think canvas itself has some bounds in it. I always forget which set of bounds you want to use because there's around 3-5 different places you can get them from

Comment: Agreed, the set routine fell through my mind's cracks. :-) I fixed it to show your comment.